Is it possible to have a large gap in various fields of science and technology at the same time?
A brief history of the world: humanity was destroyed during the nuclear Third World War.
However, a small group of scientists managed to create artificial intelligent humanoid life forms. They are created by placing a DNA sample in an environment
with a special substance, whose approximate composition is:

Nutrients (in a consistency that will allow them to dissolve in water. The presence of proteins, lipids and carbohydrates is necessary)
glucose (another saccharide is possible; the presence of sugar is mandatory)
nitrogen-containing compounds
enzymes for DNA replication as part of an artificially created replicome
trace elements (including vitamins, as well as iodine, zinc, cobalt, iron and others)
macronutrients (calcium, phosphorus, magnesium, sodium, potassium, chlorine and sulfur)
perfluorocarbons (providing liquid respiration)
oxygen (pumping gas into the tank)
temperature (low, up to critical for proteins. In the area of 36-37 Celsius)
catalyst (platinum and palladium black)

During the reactions, a living organism is obtained from DNA. The differences between modern life and people are mostly external, however
the most important of them is the lack of a reproductive system and, as a result, the ability to reproduce independently. Thus, the production of DNA and reagent for cultivation
is a priority area of activity of the new civilization. In addition, nanorobots will be created in the future, giving another leap to the development of medicine and biology.
Note: the new civilization still has such archival information about modern human technologies, such as physics, chemistry and other sciences.
The location of the story is North America, USA. Specifically, shelter where the scientists were located was located in Montana.
However, for my setting, I would like such areas as metallurgy, military industry, automobile and aircraft construction, architecture etc. to remain
at the level of the beginning of the XX century (the  limit is 40-50 years of the XX century). The question is how possible and achievable this is, and whether there will be too big a gap between these industries and medicine, biology and nanotechnology. And most importantly, can nanotechnology even appear, given the low level of development of other industries?

Sounds like your "humanoid AI" are really just vat grown sterile (perhaps gene-tweaked) humans.

It would be far more realistic if your nanotech was something that survived the war, and because of its nature (say, capability for self production that doesn't rely on complex factories, supply chains, and expert knowledge,) wasn't lost like much of the other advanced tech.

@Gene, yes, you can say so. There are external differences, but it doesn't matter in this matter.

(1) If you place a bit of DNA in an appropriate machine and amplify it what you get is lots and lots of DNA, not living organisms. (The technology already exists and it's common.) (2) If the resulting clones are sterile then something is wrong with the initial DNA; they should concentrate their efforts on obtaining good DNA, which ought to be widely available in a world which was in the recent past inhabited by 9 billion humans. Find some bones. (3) Maybe metallurgy, industry, etc. are at the level of the 1930s initially, but they won't remain there any more than they did in real history.

The substance that allows you to grow a living organism based on DNA is, of course, fictional. As for the causes of sterility, this is explained by the composition of this substance - it causes errors in DNA replication and as a result, this and similar mutations are obtained.
As for the reasons why a better sample was not found: the fact is that by that time the Third World War was already in full swing and it was not known how much time remained before the cataclysm

metallurgy is nothing but chemistry

Keep a few things in mind. (a) You're allowed to ask one and only one question. Asking more than one question is literally and specifically a reason to close the question. (b) Be careful what you include in your quesitons. If backstory isn't relevant to the quesiton, don't include it. We sometimes have problems with people judging the backstory and not the question.

so you what a schizo tech world, those are not uncommon, and it is ussually just handwaved because there is not beleivable answer. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SchizoTech


I would like such areas as metallurgy, military industry, automobile and aircraft construction, architecture etc. to remain at the level of the beginning of the XX century (the limit is 40-50 years of the XX century). The question is how possible and achievable this is...?

There's only one way, IMO, to do it...
Science, technology and innovation are massively interconnected. You'll have nanobots... but not the ability to make a car? Almost nothing is more logical than a cart (wheels, box, horse...) and the moment you have a self-motivated anything you have everything you need for an automobile.
The simple reality is that any innovation can be used to improve anything else. Materials science? Safer cars. Neural networking? Self-driving cars. Anti-matter power source? Cars that never need fuel. There isn't a technology that can't be applied to everything else.
Now, whether or not it's practical to do so is a different matter. If the smallest anti-matter power source you can make is the size of the Chrysler building then it's useful, maybe, for a very large aircraft carrier, but not a car... kinda. Suddenly you have a convenient power source to charge electric cars. See the problem?
We've been asked time and again for way to restrict or limit technology. The most popular is gunpowder. For some reason everybody wants a futuristic world that's forced to use swords for personal combat. But it always boils down to (IMO) the same solution: you're required to impose an outside force that restricts the development.
To quote from my answer to How could a really intelligent species be stopped from developing? (which quotes an even earlier answer to another question)...

"How do I retard development?" isn't an unknown question on the Stack. The fundamental problem is that evolution is naturally competitive, meaning it's filled with creatures that know how to solve problems. You want to stop them from solving problems, to act against their basic nature. There's only one way to do that if you want to avoid obvious inconsistencies in your creature's physiology and intelligence: use an outside force.

That answer (and the previous that it quotes) are addressing the idea of retarding all development. What you're doing is much, much harder. You're retarding specific development. That means having some reason to not advance those technologies... an outside force.

Limited resources (not enough metal to build cars but plenty to build nanites).

Limited reasons (no roads, efficient railroad, limited population). However, this one stretches belief because there will always be a need to haul food. The bigger your population, the more food you must haul. And once you have a need to use an automobile, holding back the tech is, IMO, impossible.

Economic prohibitions (nobody can afford their own cars or nobody can afford upgrades. Think "Cuba").

Cultural prohibitions (rebuilding after the apocalypse led to the development of a serious austerity syndrome).

Law (for reasons nobody understands, the law doesn't allow new tech to be applied to specific industries, and that law is imposed vigorously).


The real value behind this approach is that it allows you to invoke a world rule without having to deal with the reprecussions of that rule. In other words, the "outside force" is just an aesthetic, a story reason to rationalize the rule: no cars, etc. It can be anything and doesn't need to particularly associated with any other world rule.
Said another way: you already have your world rule (no cars, etc...), now you just need a bit of technobabble so you can move on with your project.

Thanks. I thought about it and came up with an idea. Since the territory is infected with radiation, and the new species is not capable of independent reproduction, then they will try to put all their efforts in this direction (growing dna and nanomachines) to the detriment of others.

The crucial step in your technology's evolution was the design of nanofactories. These are what makes growing vats possible (the reactions inside couldn't actually really take place unless there were nanobots keeping things under control), as well as limited nanotechnology.
Once pre-Fall nanotechnology was advanced enough, the powers-that-be went for self-replicating nanotechnology, which slashed costs and increased, and improved, yield.
Of course, there were safety restrictions as well as copyright and licensing problems.
So a nanofactory, provided the raw materials, is capable of, and will perform, nearly infinite self-repair, and can assemble a vast spectrum of nanobots for almost any purpose... but it won't build a copy of itself, or nanobots (or do anything) its dead masters didn't allow it to.
So you'll have a "scientist-archivist" caste for the purpose of documenting what the factories can do, and investigate ingenious workarounds to build something they shouldn't do (workarounds that lead to such gross inefficiencies, that licensing sharks simply never thought of that), up to a point. For example, it will repair its own solar panels, but not produce new solar panels. So you might be able to "produce" solar panels by ripping out one panel every so often, but no more than that. This kind of things.
Everything else, it's scavenged mid-level technology, haphazard contraptions and rediscovered 1800-level tech.
You might be able to build a humanoid, but not to intervene on human DNA because of ethical restrictions. Or build only sterile organisms because of the "Australian Rabbit Protocol". The nanofactory or its products might be fully capable of doing that, but they won't do it. And lacking the means (and the theory) to modify the software, there is no way of making them do it. Or you might be able to recode away a cancer, but the machines won't recharge your cells' telomeres - not because they can't, but because the license to do so, which did exist, costed a bomb before the Fall and was reserved for the ultra-wealthy. Actually, this kind of thing might have even been part of the reason for the Apocalypse.

The mighty supply chain
The reality is that our level of technology is a joint effort. The necessary resources, labor, automation, and precision needed to build anything are part of our existing infrastructure. If you lost that infrastructure during the war, you will have to rebuild everything by hand.
While you have all the knowledge you could possibly need at your fingertips to, say build a car, that doesn't mean you can forge an engine block in your garage.
Your plot stands on it's own. It would take decades to rebuild the infrastructure necessary to create modern cars and military equipment.
